# Boolean operation with bytes on java

Tags: java, boolean-logic

how to do the next operation between the bytes

```java
byte a;
byte b;
byte c;
byte d;

byte result = (((not(a) and(b)) or(c)) xor(d);
```

So what is the equivalent operator to **not** and **xor** in java?

Comment: What defines true and false? non-zero and `0`? `1` and `0`?

Comment: Java doesn't let you treat integer values like boolean values. You can't add `boolean`s, and you can't perform boolean logic on integers (including `byte`s).

Comment: `((~a & b) | c) ^ d` ?

Comment: Do you mean to treat these bytes as booleans (not-zero or zero); or are you asking about bitwise operations?  Please clarify.

Comment: [Java Tutorial: Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html); plus, all the byte != boolean comments.

Comment: I think what you should look for is bitwise operators

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to treat bytes as booleans (which honestly, I would be interested in knowing why, and would likely discourage you from doing so), then I recommend that you create some utility functions that return true or false based on whatever you think true and false should equate to. I'll assume here that `0` means `false` and `1` means `true`.

For example:

```
public static final boolean isTrue(byte num)  {
   return  (num == 1);
}
public static final boolean or(byte num1, byte num2)  {
   return  (isTrue(num1)  ||  isTrue(num2));
}
```

and so on. Then you can *sort-of* evaluate as you wish:

```
if(!isTrue(a)  &&  xor(c, d))  {
    //do stuff...
}
```